# Error Registering ApplicationUser: 'Invalid Column Name *_Id' using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having an issue that I have not been able to find a solution for.

I am attempting to build out a Saas Monthly billing solution similar to [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-note-taking-saas-using-aspnet-mvc-5--cms-22922).  I am using the SaasEcomm git code to add additional fields and functionality to the ApplicationUser. See below I am using the [SaasEomUser class](http://saas-ecom/SaasEcom.Core/Models/SaasEcomUser.cs) and adding additional fields and billing address.

```
public class ApplicationUser : SaasEcomUser //Instead of IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual BillingAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The error message I get makes me think Entity Framework is getting confused what the appropriate ID is but have not had any luck fixing it:

[image: Invalid column name 'SaasEcomUser_Id'.]

I don't have 'SaasEcomUser_Id' anywhere in my code so that's why I think it's Entity Framework. Here is the code (CreateAsync) that is getting called on the error:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        model.SubscriptionPlan = "basic_monthly";

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now,
                LastLoginTime = DateTime.Now,
                BillingAddress = new BillingAddress()
            };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        return View(model);
    }
```

OnModelCreating:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey<string>(m => m.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

I may be way off base but is there a way of letting EF know that the primary key is Id instead? Or is something else wrong?

Thank you to anyone that can help, in advance! If there is any other code I can provide please let me know!

Comment: Yeah, that is a modeling error. What does your OnModelCreating look like?

Comment: Thank you- I updated the code above with the method.

Comment: You might try generating a migration to see what EF is trying to do.

Comment: You can do it through package manager console. [Here is a quick start guide](http://www.codedigest.com/quick-start/12/what-is-entity-framework-code-first-migration-a-beginners-guide). When you do the first `add-migration` it will show you how EF intends to build the database. Don't worry about automatic migrations or `update-database` unless you are switching to that method of syncing model changes (the default method is via initializers like CreateDatabaseIfNotExist).

Comment: **Thank you for your help!** I was able to drop all the tables in my SQL database and run "Add-Migration InitialMigrations -IgnoreChanges".